# 10 second SSH delay prior to successful login

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh delay when connecting](https://serverfault.com/questions/183487/ssh-delay-when-connecting)

I have a Scientific Linux virtual guest running out of Virtualbox 4.0.4 on an Ubuntu 11.04 machine.

When I SSH from the host to the guest, there's *always* a 10 second pause while the public key is apparently validated.

On the client side, I see:

```
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
----10 second pause----
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
```

which corresponds to the following on the server:

```
Jul 11 20:53:05 localhost sshd[4275]: debug1: userauth-request for user ****** service ssh-connection method publickey
Jul 11 20:53:05 localhost sshd[4275]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 1
Jul 11 20:53:05 localhost sshd[4275]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
----10 second pause----
Jul 11 20:53:15 localhost sshd[4272]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.56.1"
Jul 11 20:53:15 localhost sshd[4272]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Jul 11 20:53:15 localhost sshd[4272]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
```

Any ideas why the long delay? Once connected the sessions run fine, without any lags or hangings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have an issue with reverse-DNS. Is the host you're connecting to resolving your source IP?

Comment: D'ya think? I'd (perhaps naively) assumed DNS wouldn't get involved on a 192.168 connection.

Comment: I think it does actually

Comment: Dang! You were right. Adding a mapping in /etc/hosts fixed this. Cheers.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm SURE it's not caused by DNS. I have a working DNS infrastructure, and disabling all DNS options makes no difference.

Comment: @mjk: How would it KNOW that it's a 192.168 connection before it's used DNS?

Comment: It appears (on my system) that the problem is client-side and related to IPv6. It does a number of futile IPv6 lookups before trying IPv4.