# How can I tell what is causing a delay in ssh connection startup?

Tags: ssh, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh delay when connecting](https://serverfault.com/questions/183487/ssh-delay-when-connecting)

This is a toss up between superuser and serverfault but I figure it's more a serverfaulty question.

I do development on a solaris box...

uname -a

SunOS sandbox 5.10 Generic_120011-14 sun4u sparc SUNW,UltraAX-i2

so I am constantly sshing to it via putty.

when I connect to it, I immediately get

Using username "stu".

Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key" from agent

and then it sits there for 10-20 seconds before I get my shell prompt. Never used to happen, only started recently since I've been screwing around with Xvnc, but I killed everything and I get no errors anywhere that I can find.

When I watch the /var/adm/messages file, I get this

May 15 14:16:10 sandbox sshd[15306]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted publickey for stu from 10.8.5.14 port 3363 ssh2

and then a delay, and then I get my prompt. How can I find out what's going on that's taking so long for the shell to start?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/183487/ssh-delay-when-connecting

Answer (score 1):

These delays are often caused by reverse dns lookups taking a long time, or timing out.  You don't say which sshd you are using, but in openssh, you could try `UseDNS no` in `sshd_config` on the server and see if that eliminates the delay.  If that is the case, you may leave it that way, or figure out why exactly the reverse DNS is causing problems, which could be the indication that the server has a general DNS problem, or that there is a problem specifically with looking up the PTR for your address.

Comment: not openssh, must be solaris' flavor. it didn't like that option. Not having much luck finding the equivalent in solaris sshd.

Comment: LookupClientHostnames no
 VerifyReverseMapping no

Comment: found it. didn't help. :-(