# SSH very slow when connecting from external

Tags: centos, ssh, slow-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh delay when connecting](https://serverfault.com/questions/183487/ssh-delay-when-connecting)

We have a CentOS server that we use for internal testing purposes, which has sshd enabled.
When I (as a developer) am at the company, I use `ssh root@192.168.55.131` to connect to it - and it works flawlessly.

Now, in order to work from home, accessing the server via the company's static IP, we set up another port for ssh, 2020. So I execute `ssh -p 2020 root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx` and am immediately granted for a password. After entering the password, it takes up to 30 seconds until I can access the server. Same is with SFTP (i.e. uploading files takes about 30 seconds until it begins to transfer). As you can imagine, if you have to regularly upload files to a webserver via SFTP, this is very tedious.

So I looked at similar questions and thus edited the sshd_config file on the server, setting UseDNS to "no" and GSSAPIAuthentication to "no" (this one also in ssh_config on the client) - it did not work..

Please have a look at the -vvv output when externally accessing the server:
`ssh -p 2020 -vvv root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx`

[PasteBin: ssh](http://pastebin.com/hjj7PUz5)

What could it be? Do you need more info?

Comment: Usually usedns is the reason for the delay, but moduli (http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#3.3) can also contribute to the delay. did you restart the sshd server after making changes to ssh_config?

Comment: Nope, how can I actually restart it? Looked for it in the man pages, but couldn't find it. I will look into moduli, thanks.

Comment: Is your server loaded when you are accessing it from home?

Comment: No, there are no more than, say, 2 people accessing at the same time, so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: So at what line of the debugging output does it pause, exactly? Have you also tried specifying -u0 to the OpenSSHd command line to disable DNS lookups?

Comment: Line 106 and line 112. I will try that as well, thanks.

Comment: SORRY GUYS, restarting the server solved the problem. I gave up to early, should have googled for "sshd restart"... haha. Thanks for the hint, @Hex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edited for followup:

Setting UseDNS to NO in sshd_config and restarting the sshd server fixes this issue.

Comment: Restarted the server with `/sbin/service sshd restart` on CentOS

Comment: Same problem. However, for me UseDNS yes was commented. ie #UseDNS yes. I thought it was ok. Until I figured it was probably default setting. So I corrected by uncommenting and explicitly setting UseDNS No